# Bash - How to stop searching deeper after file is found?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to complete this using native bash functionality without find etc.

Currently I am:

1. Getting a list of all filenames and putting them in an array.
2. Parsing them against a regex to find a specific filename
3. Then adding those matches to another array I use later in the script

I'd like to change this slightly to stop searching deeper in a tree if I find a match.
i.e lets say the file I'm looking for is 'test.txt'

And I have the following files:

```
./stuff/test.txt
./stuff/things/test.txt
./foo/bar/test.txt
```

I would like to only match ./stuff/test.txt, ignore the ./stuff/things/test.txt (as it has a parent match) and still find ./foo/bar/test.txt as its in a different tree from the first match.

Not too sure what the best approach is using native bash without external apps? Would value some wisdom on the best approach.

Here is my current code:

```
shopt -s globstar

    for files in **/*; do
        if [[ -f "${files}" ]]; then
            files_array+=(\./"${files}")
        fi
    done

shopt -u globstar

shopt -s nocasematch

    for such_files in "${files_array[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${such_files}" =~ ${my_custom_regex} ]]; then
            full_projects+=("${such_files}")
        fi
    done

shopt -u nocasematch`
```

Comment: As is, there's nothing you can do to avoid descending into a directory because `**/*` expands before any of your logic runs. If you want to do this as stated, you will have to manually write a recursive function that conditionally skips descending into directories that you don't want.

Comment: @that-other-guy Thanks for taking a look! Yep, I know I need to refactor, just not too sure of the best approach? I thought maybe passing the regex matches through another type of filter to remove any duplicate sub folders, then storing them again. Just curious if there is an idiomatic way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: No, there is not. Even with `find` this isn't easy to implement unless the filename is known, like `test.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this using multiple functions and arrays. Is this the most efficient way? Not too sure, but works for now.

Assuming the script can be run from anywhere and then will dive into the directory tree until it finds a regex match we:

1. Check all files in current dir script is executed from. If we find a match we are all good and can exit.
2. If no match we list the dirs in the current dir. Then iterate into them checking for matches.
3. If we find a match we stop diving. If we don't we keep diving down that tree until there are no more dirs.

More examples with some working scripts here: https://github.com/octopusnz/scripts

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

magic_reg="my_fancy_regex"
reg_matches=()
tmp_array=()
success=0

main(){

    shopt -s nocasematch

    for files in *; do
        if [[ -f "${files}" ]]; then
            if [[ "${files}" =~ ${magic_reg} ]]; then
                reg_matches+=("${PWD}")
                success=$((success+1))
                #This will only find the first one
                break
            fi
        fi
    done

    shopt -u nocasematch

    if [[ "${success}" -gt 0 ]]; then
        cleanup
    fi
}

deeper_dirs(){

  set +o nounset

  if [[ "${#tmp_array[@]}" -gt 0 ]]; then
      for deeper_files in "${tmp_array[@]}"; do
          cd "${deeper_files}"
          cust_get_files
      done
  fi

  set -o nounset

}

cust_get_files() {

    shopt -s nocasematch
    success=0

    for files in *; do
        if [[ -f "${files}" ]]; then
            if [[ "${files}" =~ ${magic_reg} ]]; then
                reg_matches+=("${deeper_files}")
                success=$((success+1))
                #This will only find the first one
                break
            fi
        fi
    done

    shopt -u nocasematch

    if [[ "${success}" -eq 0 ]]; then
        unset tmp_array
        for dirs in *; do
            if [[ -d "${dirs}" ]]; then
                tmp_array+=("${PWD}"/"${dirs}")
            fi
        done
        deeper_dirs
    fi
}

dir_check() {

    for dirs in *; do
        if [[ -d "${dirs}" ]]; then
            dirs_array+=("${PWD}"/"${dirs}")
        fi
    done

    for deeper_files in "${dirs_array[@]}"; do
        cd "${deeper_files}"
        cust_get_files
    done
}

cleanup() {

    if [[ "${#reg_matches[@]}" -lt 1 ]]; then
        printf "We didn't find any matching files. Nothing to do.\n"
        exit 0
    fi

    echo "${reg_matches[@]}"
    # We can do more neat stuff with this data here.

    exit 0
}

main
dir_check
cleanup
```